# how can I make a filter with the content of a div using html parser in java

Tags: java, html, filter, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse HTML string using htmlparser library. 
The html is like this:

```
<body>
        <div class="Level1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="txt">
                    Date of analysis:
                </div><div class="content">
                    02/03/11
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="Level1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="txt">
                    Site:
                </div><div class="content">
                    13.0E
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="Level1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="txt">
                    Network type:
                </div><div class="content">
                    DVB-S
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

I need to extract "content" information for a given "txt". I have made a filter that returns the divs with class= "level1", but I don't know how to make a filter with the content of the div, I mean in case the value of txt is Site: then read content like 13.0E.

```
  NodeList nl = parser.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("div"), new HasAttributeFilter("class", "Level1")));
```

Can someone help me with this issue?? how to read a div inside a div?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
NodeList nl = parser.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("div"), new HasAttributeFilter("class", "Level1")));
```

better to do it like this:

```
NodeList nl = parser.parse(null); // you can also filter here

NodeList divs = nl.extractAllNodesThatMatch(
  new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("DIV"), 
    new HasAttributeFilter("class", "txt")));

if( divs.size() > 0 ) {
  Tag div = divs.elementAt(0);
  String text = div.getText(); // this is the text of the div
}
```

Comment: `nl.item(0)` is the `row` element, I think we wants the div with class `txt`.

Comment: I tried your proposal but is not working... :(
The maximum that I have achived is:
    Parser parser = Parser.createParser(htmlFile, null);
    NodeList nl = parser.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("DIV"),new HasAttributeFilter("class", "txt")));        
        for(int i = 0; i < nl.size(); i++){
            Tag div = (Tag) nl.elementAt(i);
            System.out.println(div.getText());
        }
The result of the code is: div class="txt" div class="txt" div class="txt"
It's not printing the value of the div.Do you know how to print the value?